# Quarkus: PanacheMock is mocking Builder pattern

Tags: java, unit-testing, quarkus, quarkus-panache

*Disclaimer: I am Spring developer exploring Quarkus*

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/MarcoFaccani/quarkus-crud-app/tree/%40feat/getUsers)

In a straightforward Quarkus project, I've employed Hibernate with Panache to implement the Active Record Pattern. While conducting a unit test, I utilized `PanacheMock` to simulate the entity behavior and enable it to return a mock value:

```
PanacheMock.mock(UserEntity.class);
when(UserEntity.listAll()).thenReturn(userEntities());
```

The issue arises where `PanacheMock` seems to mock all static methods, including those crucial for employing the builder pattern within my test scenario:

```
UserEntity.builder()
    .id(1L)
    .username("user1")
    .city("Rome")
    .build();
```

Though I could instruct the mock to invoke the actual `.builder()` and `.build()` methods, doing so didn't work out, maybe because the Builder class itself its static.

Given that Java lacks named parameters, the creation of complex objects through a simple constructor doesn't strike me as maintainable (hence its frequent avoidance).

Could you suggest a more effective method for creating entities in Quarkus? I believe I am missing "the Quarkus way" of doing things

Comment: It seems what you're after is partial mocking. `PanacheMock` doesn't seem to support that directly, but it should be possible to use `PanacheMock.doCallRealMethod().when(UserEntity.class).builder()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ladicek. That's indeed what I meant when I said "Though I could instruct the mock to invoke the actual .builder() and .build() methods, doing so didn't work out, maybe because the Builder class itself its static.", perhaps I didn't mange to express myself :)

Comment: Ah OK, sorry for misunderstanding. I believe that it _should_ work (and that it's the right thing to do).